# SQL key related error

Tags: mysql, sql

There's an error in this code probably related to the key, I'm doing something wrong here. (AAAAAA is my test string)

```
insert ignore into ARCUS (COMPANY_CD, CUSTOMER_NO, RECORD_KEY.COMPANY_CD.CUSTOMER_NO.OPTIONAL_SHIPTO) values ('CU', 'AAAAAA', 'CUAAAAAA    ');
```

Comment: This `RECORD_KEY.COMPANY_CD.CUSTOMER_NO.OPTIONAL_SHIPTO` does not make sense as a column name.

Comment: Why not? I copied it straight from the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround with ` (quote). In this case, RECORD_KEY.COMPANY_CD.CUSTOMER_NO.OPTIONAL_SHIPTO